# Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: JAVA HEAP SPACE while converting xlsx to csv format. I tried this no luck <java-opts>-Xms400m -Xmx4096m</java-opts>

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.base.Joiner;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;

import static org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted;

public class XlsxToCsv {

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    private XSSFSheet excelSheet;
    private String outputFile;
    private String defaultFS;
    private List<String[]> arrayCSV = new ArrayList<>();

    // Minumun amount of rows to expect
    private int minRows = 5;

    // Escape char for hive
    private String escapeStr = "\\";

    // Escape char for csv
    private String separatorStr = ",";

    public XlsxToCsv(String inputFile, String outputFile, String excelSheet, String defaultFS) throws IOException {
        this.outputFile = outputFile;
        this.defaultFS = defaultFS;
        this.excelSheet = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile)).getSheet(excelSheet);
    }

    public void setMinRows(int minRows) {
        this.minRows = minRows;
    }

    public void setEscapeStr(String escapeStr) {
        this.escapeStr = escapeStr;
    }

    public void setSeparatorStr(String separatorStr) {
        this.separatorStr = separatorStr;
    }

    public List<String[]> getArrayCSV() {
        return arrayCSV;
    }

    private void convertToCsv() {
        Cell cell;

        try {

            for (Row row : excelSheet) {
                int lastColumnNum = Math.max(row.getLastCellNum(), minRows);
                String[] rowArray = new String[lastColumnNum];

                for (int count = 0; count < lastColumnNum; count++) {
                    cell = row.getCell(count, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);

                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                            rowArray[count] = isCellDateFormatted(cell) ? dateFormat.format(cell.getDateCellValue()) : Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            rowArray[count] = Boolean.toString(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            rowArray[count] = isCellDateFormatted(cell) ? dateFormat.format(cell.getDateCellValue()) : Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            rowArray[count] = cell.getStringCellValue().replace(separatorStr, escapeStr + separatorStr).replace("\n", " ");
                            break;
                        default:
                            rowArray[count] = "";
                    }
                }

                arrayCSV.add(rowArray);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void writeCsv() {
        try {
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(defaultFS), new Configuration());
            FSDataOutputStream outputStream = fs.create(new Path(outputFile));

            Joiner joinEmpty = Joiner.on("").skipNulls();
            Joiner joinComma = Joiner.on(separatorStr).skipNulls();

            for (String[] i : arrayCSV) {
                if (joinEmpty.join(i).length() > 0) {
                    outputStream.writeBytes(joinComma.join(i) + "\n");
                }
            }

            outputStream.hflush();
            outputStream.hsync();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String inputFile = args[0];
        String outputFile = args[1];
        String excelSheet = args[2];
        String defaultFS = args[3];

        XlsxToCsv processExcelFile = new XlsxToCsv(inputFile, outputFile, excelSheet, defaultFS);
        processExcelFile.convertToCsv();
        processExcelFile.writeCsv();

        Joiner joinEmpty = Joiner.on("").skipNulls();
        Joiner joinComma = Joiner.on(",").skipNulls();

        for (String[] record : processExcelFile.getArrayCSV()) {
            if (joinEmpty.join(record).length() > 0) {
                System.out.print(joinComma.join(record));
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While converting the xlsx to csv I am facing below error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space  
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:77)  
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource$FakeZipEntry.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:123)  
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:57)  
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:93)  
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:278)  
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)  
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:274)  
at acvx.agg.qwuer.excel.XlsxToCsv.<init>(XlsxToCsv.java:43)  
at acvx.agg.qwuer.excel.XlsxToCsv.main(XlsxToCsv.java:135)
```

Comment: Seems to me that you're processing the entire file in memory and *then* writing the file to disk. That's going to use a lot of memory to process a large file. Instead, process a smaller number of rows before writing them to the file, then process X more rows, write them, process X more, etc... and your memory footprint will go down considerably.

Comment: my file size is  50kb only

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:
1) I suspect you are reading the excel line by line but there may not be data after some lines and there looks to be no check in your program for that !
2) I suggest try editing this to run only for 50 lines, you will get a good idea that if you excel is 250 lines it can convert that part.
3) If you get success above, try going in loops of reads and writes, currently you are reading everything to array and then next function of writing everything. Just suggesting to break this, say read 10 and write 10. ensure you make your variables null after this so that  they are available for garbage collection
4) The eclipse size increase is dependent on total RAM of your machine, you cannot go beyond a point for a given machine, so i agree that might not necessarily solve your problem.